# Calculate shortest path to leaf from root

Tags: tree, shortest-path

I have a tree. Every node has, on average, about 8 children. The depth of the tree is about 150, and is the same for every path. What is a good way to find the cheapest path to a leaf?

This seems impossible to me, as there will be about 8^150 paths?

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of tree path algorithms that are far more efficient than brute forcing it - one example I tend to use is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm (which has O(ElogV) complexity, much better than brute-forcing it!), and there are a wide variety of algorithms to choose from, depending on if your tree has weighted paths or unweighted paths, the distributions you tend to expect, if it's directed or undirected and so on.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem has a better overview of the various types of algorithms used for solving this problem.